# Row edit iterator in Apache Accumulo

Tags: java, accumulo

I'm working with Apache Accumulo and I need to create a iterator that every minor compaction scans all whole row and create a MD5 of two column and save it as another column of my row...

Example:

I insert this data:

```
|| Row || colFam || colQual || value ||
||=====||========||=========||=======||
|| A   || person || name    || Bob   ||
|| A   || person || surname || Smith ||
|| A   || work   || place   || Bank  ||
|| B   || person || name    || Jhon  || 
|| B   || person || surname || Allen ||
|| B   || work   || place   || Pub   ||
...
...
```

I need a iterator that every time I write a row (A or B with all its colFam e colQual) it get the value of two column (name and surname) and calculate the MD5 of the resulting string (name + surname) and save it as a column of my row.

The result should be like that:

```
|| Row || colFam || colQual || value        ||
||=====||========||=========||==============||
|| A   || person || name    || Bob          ||
|| A   || person || surname || Smith        ||
|| A   || work   || place   || Bank         ||
|| A   || MD5    || MD5     || <MD5 result> || <--
|| B   || person || name    || Jhon         || 
|| B   || person || surname || Allen        ||
|| B   || work   || place   || Pub          ||
|| B   || MD5    || MD5     || <MD5 result> || <--
....
....
```

I think that I can put this iterator on a minor(/major) compaction of a table.

Any idea? Which one of the Built-In iterator I have to extend to do that?

Thank you so much

Comment: So what's your problem. Provide some more info what you need

Comment: @GajendraKChauhan here you are! :)

Comment: It's my subject of interest :)

Comment: I'm having trouble parsing what your question is, but from what I can piece together, it sounds like you're looking to extend the WholeRowIterator to write new values on compaction?  You could do this, but depending on what you're trying to accomplish, this might not be the best approach.  There will be a window between when the data is "in" the table and when it's written to HDFS (minor compaction) where you'll have rows without any MD5 result.

Comment: Ok, so i need to calculate and add to all my rows a column for MD5 of other two columns. I think that do it with iterators will be the best way.. but I'm not an expert and i don't know how to do that.. I think that I need to extend a WholeRowIterator and then for each row add a new column (with a batchwriter)... Is it right?

Comment: A similar application is an iterator that for each row insert a column in which writes how many columns there are in that row... I need to: get data from a single row (= get columns of a row), process that data in some way (in my case calculate MD5,...) and then put the output of the processing into a new column with that output as value. Any help??

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [TransformingIterator](https://github.com/apache/accumulo/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/apache/accumulo/core/iterators/user/TransformingIterator.java). This iterator tries to hide some of the complexities behind row-level operations.

The general strategy is that, when iterating over a row, you have to buffer the row in memory, perform your computation, and then write out the row in the correct sorted order.